# Obtaining the coordinates of point through arcpy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I have a feature selected from a feature class based on user input through arcpy.

How can I obtain the x,y coordinate of the selected point feature class (Points).

How do I do this?:

```
arcpy.AddMessage ("Coordinates: " + Points.getSelectedExtent().X)
```

Comment: Is there already X, Y coordinates associated with the data?

Comment: No x,y coordinate are not present in the feature attribute table.

Answer (score 4):

you can create a cursor (arcpy.da.searchCursor) with

SHAPE@XY —A tuple of the feature's centroid x,y coordinates

which gives you directly the X and Y of the selected points

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(Points, "SHAPE@XY",  """ "Name"='%s' """ %Point_Name) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print("{0}, {1}".format(row[0][0], row[0][1]))
```

EDIT: just in case, the X coordinate of the center of the extent of a feature class is :

```
arcpy.Describe(featureclas).extent.XMax - arcpy.Describe(featureclas).extent.XMin
```

Comment: Doesnt help mcuh. What is a cursor type. All I have is a shape file in the variable name "Points". How do I get the center x,y coordinates of the selected feature in "Points".

Comment: do you want the coordinates of the points in a given feature class or the extent of a feature class of points ?

Comment: I want coordinates of the points in a given feature class selection.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. Maybe if you add some code or an illustration I could see your problem. Do you mean that the user gives the name of a feature class (e.g. myshape.shp) that contains points and that you want to know the center of those points. Or that the user selects one feature of the feature class (in practice, the selection has to be stored in a layer, or you can directly use its whereclause in the searchcursor).

Comment: @radouxju See my comment on the question - they don't yet have x and y coordinates associated with the layer.

Comment: not in the attribute table, but I get it from the geometry with shape@8xy . What I need to know is exactly WHAT the OP selects (a feature in a feature class, a group of features in a feature class or a feature class) and HOW he does the selection in Python (bt attribute, by location ?)

Comment: OK., I make a single selection, one feature selection from a point shape file based on user input through this code. arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(Points, "NEW_SELECTION", "Name ='%s'" %Point_Name)

Comment: After making the selection, how do I obtain the x,y coordinate of the selected feature using ArcPy

Comment: OK, so you don't even need the selection. you can directly set """ "Name"='%s' """ %Point_Name as the whereclause